# Render/redirect to an existing JQuery dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Some context: I'm attempting to avoid e-mail based confirmation by putting up a modal asking the user to confirm his e-mail address and phone number the first time a he attempts to perform a substantive action in my Rails 4 application.

This modal is a JQuery Dialog, which loads an abbreviated user form, containing only the user's contact info. The user can update his information and click Submit, or simply click Submit to confirm that the information is correct.

I have some code in my users controller that handles the form submission and redirects to different views in a standard way:

```
    if update_required
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update(attribs)
          puts "update succeeded"
          format.html { render :confirmation_update, :layout => false }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
        else
          puts "update failed dismally"
          format.html { render :confirmation, :layout => false, alert: 'there were errors'}
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

My problem is that that the forms that get rendered on success/fail get rendered in the main window, and I'd like them to be rendered in the existing JQuery dialog window. Is there a way I can specify the target where these views will be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, you have to send this requests like ajax calls.
First your previous form has to have remote:true in his options and your action must response with a js:

```
if update_required
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(attribs)
      puts "update succeeded"
      format.js { render :confirmation_update }
    else
      puts "update failed dismally"
      format.js { render :confirmation }
    end
  end
end
```

This files confirmation_update and confirmation has to be js.erb with the next content like example for Jquery dialog:

```
$('#myModal').html("<%= j render('confirmation_content')%>");
$('#myModal').dialog('open');
```

The error messages in confirmation.js.erb:

```
$('#flash').html("there were errors");
```

With this example the file _confirmation_content.html.erb should be created and has to be a rails partial with the content of the modal.